# Query to get no of drivers who hasn't taken any trips in last 7 days from from their latest ride for country of =150

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got two tables
Fact_trips (tb)       dim_city(tb)

```
Driver I'd.           City id
Trip id                country id
Rider I'd
Time stamp
City id
```

The question is to get drivers who hasn't done any ride for last 7 days from their latest ride in country 150

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it work? That sample data(?) doesn't make much sense either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and see [what is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Select count(driverid) as total from(                                     
      Selectt A.driver_id, max(timestam) , timestamp,as date from fact_trips as A join dimcity as b on a.city id = b.city id.  Where country= 194 . Group by driverid , timestamp                 ) as K where datediff(dw, timestamp, date) <= 7 I tried this query but it is not working as since I put time stamp in group by it is taking it is grouping each row

Answer (score 0):

We can check whether the driver_is is in a sub-query to get the drivers who have been to a city in country 150 in the last 7 days and exclude them with `not in`.

> ```
> create table  Fact_trips (Driver_id int, Trip_id int, Rider_id int, Time date, city_id int);
> create table dim_city (City_id int, country_id int);
> insert into dim_city values
> (1,150),(2,250);
> insert into Fact_trips values
> (1,1,1,'2022-04-01',1),
> (3,1,1,'2022-04-10',2),
> (2,1,1,'2022-04-08',1);
> GO
> ```

5 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select t.driver_id 
> from Fact_trips t
> where t.driver_id not in
> (
> select f.driver_id
> from fact_trips f
> join dim_city c
> on f.city_id = c.city_id
> where [Time] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
> and country_id = 150
>  )
> ```

> ```
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | driver_id |
> | --------: |
> |         1 |
> |         3 |
> ```

> ```
> select f.driver_id
> from fact_trips f
> join dim_city c
> on f.city_id = c.city_id
> where [Time] >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
> and country_id = 150
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | driver_id |
> | --------: |
> |         2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f54fb47ab9a9c03da9640df3ee091cf)*